# Suggestions for a command line IRC client that supports downloads?

Tags: command-line, software-rec, irc

It's been awhile since I've used IRC and the last time I did was on a windows system with mIRC. I'm interested in finding a command line client that supports downloads and some degree of automation for those downloads. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For commandline IRC, the most popular or commonly-used one is probably [irssi](http://www.irssi.org).  It's very robust, very flexible, highly extensible with scripts and layout themes, very well-documented, and has a decent community of users and supporters.